# iText digital signature exception:Cannot recover key?

Tags: pdf-generation, itext, digital-signature, keystore

Am running the code which is taken from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14956356/what-is-wrong-in-this-implementation-of-itext-digital-signing),But i am getting the following exception,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key
    at sun.security.provider.KeyProtector.recover(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineGetKey(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineGetKey(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.KeyStore.getKey(Unknown Source)
    at com.seind.pdf.digitalsignature.SimpleSignature.main(SimpleSignature.java:89)
```

1. am using itext
   5.3.4.jar,bcpkix-jdk15on-1.47.jar,bcprov-jdk15on-1.47.jar
2. am using the following command to create a key store
   $ keytool -genkey -alias foobar -keyalg RSA -keystore .keystore

can anyone help me to identify the cause of the exception.....